# Magento Auto fill opengraph description using seo meta description

Tags: magento2

I have a opengraph module installed. we have two product eav attributes og_title and og_desc. When I am adding a new product, i want og_title field to be autofilled to product title and og_desc to be autofilled to meta description.

I have included custom Js on new product page. and it autofills only if opengraph group is opened on a manual click as the fieldset appears after i manually open the group. Here is the code

catalog_product_new.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Test_Notifications::js/opengraphseocustom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

opengraphseocustom.js

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'uiRegistry',
    'prototype'
], function ($, registry) {
    //'use strict';
    console.log("test");

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {

    var productTitleInput = registry.get('inputName = product[name]');
    console.log(productTitleInput);

    // Attach a custom event handler to capture changes
    if (productTitleInput) {
        
    }

    $('div[data-index="open-graph-metadata"]').click();

    $('input[name="product[name]"]').on('keyup' ,function () {
        var title = $(this).val();
        console.log("title" + title);
        var ogTitleInput = $('input[name="product[og_title]"]');
        ogTitleInput.val(title);
        
    });
});    
});
});
```

I want the og_title and og_desc field to be autofilled to title and meta description as i enter it in their respective fields without manually opening the opengraph group